# Invalid Column Name SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I keep getting an error that says Invalid Column name'a'. Can anyone help?

```
Select 
datename(mm,t.gift_date) as month, 
s.campaign as campaign, 
count(s.Campaign) as a
From usga_stage.facts.transactions t, usga_dw.dbo.DimSourceCode s
Where t.trans_source=s.SourceCode
and t.payment_channel = 'Web'
and t.gift_date like '2013%'
Group by month(t.gift_date),Campaign, a
```

order by month(t.gift_date), campaign, a

Comment: remove `a` from your `group by`. You don't need the aggregate in the `GROUP BY` statement

Answer (score 6):

You can't group by an ALIAS, nor do you need to group by an aggregate field:

```
Select 
month(t.gift_date) as month, 
s.campaign as campaign, 
count(s.Campaign) as a
From usga_stage.facts.transactions t, usga_dw.dbo.DimSourceCode s
Where t.trans_source=s.SourceCode
and t.payment_channel = 'Web'
and t.gift_date like '2013%'
Group by month(t.gift_date),Campaign
```

You can use aliases in the `ORDER BY` section, just not `GROUP BY`

Also, it's good practice to use explicit joins, like this:

```
SELECT month(t.gift_date) as month
      ,s.campaign as campaign
      ,count(s.Campaign) as a
FROM usga_stage.facts.transactions t
JOIN usga_dw.dbo.DimSourceCode s
  ON t.trans_source = s.SourceCode
WHERE t.payment_channel = 'Web'
  and t.gift_date like '2013%'
GROUP BY MONTH(t.gift_date)
        ,Campaign
```

Comment: +1, but, since you are a knowledgeable SQL guy, please try to teach new users when you see bad practices. In this case, op shouldn't be using old, deprecated, implicit `JOIN`s

Comment: Thanks! I was writing this quickly to see what results it would bring back. I took that out and I still received an error. I rewrote the query and it worked.                                         Select 
month(t.gift_date) as 'month', 
s.campaign, 
count(t.account_id) as counts
From usga_stage.facts.transactions t
JOIN usga_dw.dbo.DimSourceCode s
ON t.trans_source=s.SourceCode
Where t.payment_channel = 'Web'
and t.gift_date  like '2013%'
Group by month(t.gift_date), s.Campaign